# How to reset entered data of xp:inputs?

Tags: xpages

I've created a simple XPage containing a datasource, an input an a cancel button. 
As it is a *cancel*-button, I expect the page to reload and the input gets cleared.

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1"></xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>

<xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document1.Subject}"></xp:inputText>


<xp:button value="Cancel" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" 
        submit="true" 
        refreshMode="complete" 
        immediate="true" 
        save="false">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

But the result is, that the entered value is still shown. 
When I click the button, a *POST*-request sends the entered value to the server, and responds with that uploaded data.

Request body contains:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="view:_id1:inputText1"

test
-----------------------------78781723514850
```

Response contains the entered value:

```
<input type="text" value="test" id="view:_id1:inputText1" name="view:_id1:inputText1" class="xspInputFieldEditBox">
```

How do I reset the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reload the page** with the same URL including parameters when Cancel button is clicked. This will reset all input values.

Add `context.redirectToPage(context.getUrl().toString())` to your Cancel button as SSJS code:

```xml
<xp:button value="Cancel" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" 
        submit="true" 
        refreshMode="complete" 
        immediate="true" 
        save="false">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            context.redirectToPage(context.getUrl().toString())
        }]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

An alternative is to use the **partial execution mode**. It ignores the submitted values for all (input) controls but the button itself.

[image]

```xml
<xp:button value="Cancel" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" 
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete"
        immediate="true"
        save="false"
        execMode="partial">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

You can find more information about partial execution mode [here](http://www.intec.co.uk/partial-execution-mode-probably-the-most-powerful-xpages-feature-you-dont-use/).

Comment: **partialExecutionMode** solved my problem. I wanted to avoid a redirect to the same page and a complete refresh of the page. Your solution works in partial refresh too. Great, thank you!